# Losing minimized app instances

Tags: unity, window

Ok, to start off, I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 (beta) on my 2010 Macbook.

The problem I'm having is that when I have multiple instances of an application running and I minimize one I lose it. I've tried alt-tab, Super-w and any other shortcuts I could find on the net, but nothing will bring back the minimized window. It only brings up the active window(s). Again, clicking on the dock icon only brings up an expo-type display of the active application windows, no minimized ones.

If someone could tell me a keyboard shortcut or SOMETHING to work around this I would eternally grateful. This is really getting on my nerves and presents serious issues when I'm working on a research paper and keep losing my Chromium windows.

Comment: This question is about a Compiz bug, that has been fixed in the meantime. Vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 0):

I would humbly suggest you use a dock such as [docky](http://packages.ubuntu.com/docky) [image: Install docky], at least until you can figure out the problem.

Also, I believe you may be experiencing a bug, as this is not normal behavior in Unity. I would suggest reporting a bug on Launchpad (as soon as possible).

Comment: I love docky actually. I've just been trying to learn unity. It's actually pretty nice. They've made it much more usable in 11.10 But, anyways thanks for the response. I installed the full 11.10 release today and the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem with Oneiric stable on a PC. If I minimized one window, I couldn't restore it without closing the other open instances of the same app.

To fix it, open `gconf-editor` and go to

```
/apps/compizconfig-1/profiles/Default/plugins/workarounds/screen0/options/
```

And enable **keep_minimized_windows**